# Using the document store as a cache

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, nest

I've set up a basic implementation of ElasticSearch, storing a couple of fields in the document and I'm able to execute queries.

```cs
var searchResult = client.Search<SearchTest>(s =>
    s
    .Size(1000)
    .Fields(f => f.ID)
    .Query(q => q.QueryString(d => d.Query(query)))
    )
    .Documents.Select(item =>
        item.ID
        )
    .ToList();

var products = this.DbContext.Products
    .Where(item =>
        searchResult.Contains(item.ProductId)
        && ...
        )
    .Select(item => ...);

// subsequent queries here
```

Right now, I simply return the index, which I use in database queries to retrieve a whole lot of information. The information stored in the documents is also retrieved. Now I'm wondering, should I skip retrieving this from the database, and use the data in the document store? Or should I use it for nothing else but searching?

Some context: searching in a product database, some information is always the same, some information (like price calculation) depends on which customer is searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a hard and fast answer to this question.  I like to pull enough information from the index to populate a list of search results, but retrieve the full contents of the document from others, external sources (ex. a database).  Entirely subjectively, this seems to be the more common use of Lucene, from what I've seen.

Storage strategy, as far as I know, should not have a direct impact on search performance, but keeping data stored for each document to a minimum will improve performance retrieving documents from the index (ie, for that list of results mentioned before).

I'm also sometimes hesitant to make Lucene the system of record.  It seems to be much easier to find yourself with a broken/corrupt index than a database.  I like having the option available to trash and rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

I see you already accepted an answer but i'd like to offer a second approach.

Elasticsearch excels at storing Documents (json) and so retrieving complete object graphs can be a very fast and powerful approach to overcome the impedance mismatch and N+1 sensitive database queries.

To me the best approach would be for `searchResults` to already be the list of definitive `IEnumerable<Product>` without having to do N database queries afterwards.

Elasticsearch (unlike raw lucene or even Solr) has a special field that stores the original json graph called `_source` so the overhead of loading your whole document is very minimal.

This comes at the cost of having to basically write your data twice, once to the database and once to elasticsearch on every mutation. Depending on your architecture this may or may not be achievable.

I agree with @femtoRgon that being able to reindex from an external datasource is a good idea, but the Elasticsearch developers are working very hard to get a proper backup and restore going for 1.0. This will greatly reduce the need for the second datastorage.

BTW not sure if you are aware but specifying `.Fields()` will already force Elasticsearch to only load up the specified fields instead of the whole graph from the special `_source` field.

Comment: There's a lot of legacy code using (and modifying) this data already, right now it's unclear if we can write to ES or if we'll have to reindex at intervals. Thanks for the info!